# Задание width для img в процентах

Tags: css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, responsive, кроссбраузерность

Для достижения "резиновой" верстки задал картинке (svg в img) ширину в процентах (35%). Всё работало отлично в хроме, но на этапе проверки кроссбраузерности обнаружилась проблема в Firefox. Сам расчёт в процентах там работает тоже, но считает по другому. Картинка в итоге получается меньше и от этого другие элементы верстки "плывут".

С чем это может быть связано или каким образом можно написать грамотный "костыль" для решения проблемы в FF?

Спасибо!

Comment: Единственное решение, которое вижу на данный момент: проверять в js браузер пользователя и для ff переопределять ширину большим значением.
Но тогда при определенной ширине экрана картинка наоборот, становится шире чем в хроме

Comment: Видимо в FF отличается алгоритм расчёта относительной ширины (в хроме и опере всё правильно рассчитывается относительно родительского контейнера, а в ff -- нет), поэтому еще одним вариантом решения я нашел задание ширины в процентном соотношении от родительского через js, а не средствами непонятно как работающих алгоритмов css

Comment: способ описанный в прошлом комментарии тоже не помог, т.к. несмотря на прямую заданную ширину в пикселях рассчитанную через js относительн